# Implementing Fragments Androids

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am implementing fragments for the first time so please help me.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
            android:id="@+id/viewer"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want that fragment having the id as 'list' should remain constant but the the fragment having id 'viewer' should be able to call different classes.

(Note that the classes extend Activity.)

My question is simple: I have four classes(Extending ACTIVITY). I want to divide the screen into two parts. The left Side remains constant which contains the listview. On list view's click I want to open my Class(Extending ACTIVITY), but only in the right portion(remaining screen).

Comment: As you can see on FAQ, your question has to basically be a "a specific programming problem", which is not this case. You're not asking anything that can be pointed out easily, but instead a do-it-for-me question.

Comment: i viewed many related examples, but all had 'multiple fragments in a single activity' but i am trying to get 'multiple activities in a single fragment'.

Comment: any help regarding the problem's solution appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the android documentation of fragments:
**A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).**

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

what i understood from your question is that you want to the content of your fragement `viewer` at run-time. a possible solution which i can suggest for this is:
Instead of your four classes extending `Activity`, extend `Fragment`, each having its own layout. Modify the main layout file to look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the FrameLayout will basically act as a container for your fragments, which you can dynamically load at run-time(by clicking the ListView). This tutorial will help you out with it:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Hope my answer helps you in some way.

Comment: The Frame Layout will act as a container for fragment not for the activity. I want that the frame layout you specified acts as the container to Activity.

Comment: look you are missing out the purpose of fragments. fragments are the mechanism provided by android if you want to avoid using intents and separate activities. a fragment allows you to modularize your activity. you cannot add another activity within an activity. fragments are there for this very purpose. they can be embedded within an activity, and can send and receive data just like activities.you cannot start an activity on the same screen as another activity. starting a new activity will automatically take you to the next screen. but fragments provide the functionality which you require.

Comment: also try to understand that an activity can be composed of multiple fragments and not vice versa.

Comment: I wanted to use the activities which i already wrote earlier. seems I have to write my classes extending FRAGMENT all over again. 
Is that what you want to say???????

Comment: yes, that would be the correct way of achieving what you want,and that is also what everybody else here has been trying to explain to you.because it is not possible to embed an activity within another. go through the links that I have posted, working with fragments may be a bit tricky but once you get the hang of it, its not too tough. I am also an android newbie and have implemented a similar thing in one of my apps. One fragment is declared in the layout file, and the other is added dynamically at run-time. if you have anymore doubts feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It is a basic question. You should start from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). And [this topic](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) can help you also.

Comment: The example here is class specific i.e. we specify a class in the xml itself. i want to use different classes(each class is an activity class)which are the result of clicking on the list items on the left fragment.

Comment: thanks for showing your concern in answering my question. Please help.

Comment: you cant display tow activities in one time. You should implement fragments to show your content in and place them in one activity. Communication between fragments can be done through container activity

Comment: My question is simple:

I have four classes(Extending ACTIVITY). 

I want to divide the screen into two parts. The left Side remains constant which contains the listview.

On list view's click I want to open my Class(Extending ACTIVITY), but only in the right portion(remaining screen).

Comment: Read about fragments from the first link please. You can't implement what you describe. You should extend Fragment instead Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are like seperate acticities, so unless u make the changes the action on one fragment will not affect the other fragments.
Assuming u have a listview on the left fragment, in its activity place a onItemClickListener.
For each itemclick switch the activity on the right fragment.

Sample Code for the OnItemClick Event

```
Fragment fragment=new activity1();
fragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame2,fragment);
ft.commit();
```

In the above code segment **activity1** is the new class want to attach to the right fragment. R.id.frame2 is the id of the framelayout that is used with the right fragment.

Comment: @sneaker_android A little bit of code that u used will help in guiding u better.

Comment: But according to your code activity1 should extend fragment but my activity1 extends Activity. :( .......

Answer (score 0):

The Fragment class can be used many ways to achieve a wide variety of results. In its core, it represents a particular operation or interface that is running within a larger Activity. A Fragment is closely tied to the Activity it is in, and can not be used apart from one. Though Fragment defines its own lifecycle, that lifecycle is dependent on its activity: if the activity is stopped, no fragments inside of it can be started; when the activity is destroyed, all fragments will be destroyed.

```
    MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();// MyFragment is a Fragment class
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.fra,newFragment, tag);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
```

[sample code](http://www.ziddu.com/download/21506095/fragment.zip.html)

in sample code  change

```
          ft.add(android.R.id.content,fragTwo, "tag");
```

to

```
          ft.add(R.id.fra,fragTwo, "tag");
```

and add some code in detail.java

```
                 public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tv.setText(data);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            fm.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragTwo = new MyFragment();
            //String tag = getActivity().GetFragmentID();
            Fragment f= fm.findFragmentById(getId());
            ft.replace(R.id.fra,fragTwo, "tag");
            ft.hide(f);  
            ft.commit(); 


        }
    });


    super.onStart();
}
```